# how to uniquely identify a table from a view and also separate the 1:1 and logic from the view?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Hi All i am trying to extract the corresponding table from a view ,but here is a catch , is it possible to find out whether the view is just a 1:1 copy from a underlying table or does it have any specific logic ?

**Database - Oracle 11g**

the first part of the question - find the table of the corresponding view

**reference :** https://dataedo.com/kb/query/oracle/list-tables-used-by-a-view

```
select owner as schema_name,
       name as view_name,
       referenced_owner as referenced_schema_name,
       referenced_name,
       referenced_type
from sys.dba_dependencies
-- excluding some Oracle maintained schemas
where owner not in ('ANONYMOUS','CTXSYS','DBSNMP','EXFSYS', 'LBACSYS', 
   'MDSYS', 'MGMT_VIEW','OLAPSYS','OWBSYS','ORDPLUGINS', 'ORDSYS','OUTLN', 
   'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA','SYS','SYSMAN','SYSTEM','TSMSYS','WK_TEST','WKSYS', 
   'WKPROXY','WMSYS','XDB','APEX_040000', 'APEX_PUBLIC_USER','DIP', 
   'FLOWS_30000','FLOWS_FILES','MDDATA', 'ORACLE_OCM', 'XS$NULL',
   'SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR', 'SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR', 'PUBLIC') 
and name ('USE_MY_LIST_OF_VIEWS') --> i can insert all the views in order to find out
order by owner, name, referenced_name, referenced_owner, referenced_type;
```

but here is a problem from the above query there is a high probability that view can be used many tables in my case

so i have tried with

```
select * from dba_views
and name ('USE_MY_LIST_OF_VIEWS') --> i can insert all the views in order to find out
order by name ;
```

but this doesn't solve my question ,

**1) so how to identify unique table**

**2) is it possible to find out whether the view is just a 1:1 copy from a underlying table or does it have any specific logic ?**

any suggestions on a simplified and effective way to achieve 1) & 2)  ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  The `dba_dependencies` query shows the tables that a view depends on directly (there may be additional tables on which the view depends if you have nested views, function calls, etc.).  What does it mean to you to "identify unique table"?  Are you looking for a list of views that have a dependency on a single table?  Something else?  As for "1:1 copy", is that literal?  No changes in column names, column orders, no transforms, no filters?  Or are there really differences that you want to ignore (i.e. column order)?

Comment: @JustinCave - yes dba_dependencies shows the tables associated with specific view ,but i would like to get the table from which the view is created , unique table means whether the view is created by a combination of many tables, Are you looking for a list of views that have a dependency on a single table - yes  (1:1 copy), column order doesn't matter

Comment: What is the difference in your mind between a table "associated with the specific view", which I assume means a table on which the view depends if you're querying `dba_dependences`, and a "table from which the view is created"?  As with most questions, examples are awfully helpful, i.e. "If I create view X, I want the query to return Y because Z.  If I create view A, I want the query to return B, because C".

Comment: That `not in` list could probably be simplified to `not in (select u.username from dba_users u where u.oracle_maintained = 'Y' )`

Comment: @WilliamRobertson i have check DBA_USER table there is no field called oracle_maintained

Comment: @rakesh Just checked and looks like it was added in [12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-309FCCB2-2E8D-4371-9FC5-7F3B10E2A8C0.htm).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson as mentioned my db is 11g